# Prove F is continuous in the [0,2] interval even if f is not.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be
$$f(x) =\Biggr\{ \begin{matrix}
    x,  \;\;\; x\in[0,1] \\
    x+1, ;\;\; x\in(1,2]\\
  \end{matrix} $$

We define $F$ with $F(0) = 0\;$ and

$$F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt, \;\;\; x \in (0,2]$$

Determine $F$ and prove that $F$ is continuous in the $[0,2]$ interval even if $f$ is not.

I did the integral of $f(x)$ and I obtained these results:

$$F(x) =\Biggr\{ \begin{matrix}
    \frac{x^2}{2},  \;\;\; x\in[0,1] \\
    \frac{x^2}{2}+x+C, \;\;\; x\in(1,2]\\
  \end{matrix} $$

I did the lateral limits as well, but $F(x)$ continued without being continuous. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With this definition of $F$ it is constant, because it doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: I think you meant x, not 2, as the limit of the integral in the first integral

Comment: Note that the continuity of $F(x)$ follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus (or at least a slight generalization of it); If $f(x)$ is integrable, then $F(x)$ is continuous. $f(x)$ is integrable because it has a single jump discontinuity.

Comment: Yes, I have just corrected it.

Comment: If C=-1 then F(x) is continuous ?

Comment: It is easy prove via definition of continuity that any function of the form $\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ for $x \in (0,2]$

Now, for $x \in (0,1]$ we have $F(x)=\int_0^x tdt=\frac{x^2}{2}$

Instead, for $x \in (1,2]$ we have $F(x)=\int_0^1 tdt + \int_1^x (t+1) dt=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x-\frac{1}{2}-1=\frac{x^2}{2}+x-1$

Clearly $F$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$ but taking the limits at $1$ and $F(1)$ we can see that they all coincide and they are equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $F(x)$ is continuous on $[0,2]$.